"imprisonment for ten years" VS "imprisonment of ten years" VS "ten years' imprisonment"
my own examples:
(1) imprisonment for ten years
(2) imprisonment of ten years
(3) ten years' imprisonment
As far as I understand, they are all correct.
What's the difference between them?

There's no difference worth putting into words or committing to memory, but of is relatively uncommon because we usually use that when referring to the imprisonment of the criminal gang for ten years. But a [prison] sentence is semantically and syntactically the same as imprisonment, and we certainly talk about sentences of at least five years.

@FumbleFingers You wrote: "we certainly talk about sentences of at least five years". Does it mean "a sentence of five years" is correct but "a sentence for five years" is not? Thanks.

No. It just means  "a sentence of five years" is more common than "a sentence for five years". Stop obsessing over "correct / incorrect" and possible differences of nuance. Some prepositions are more common than others in specific contexts, but which choice is the most common often changes over time anyway.

@FumbleFingers You wrote: "Stop obsessing over "correct / incorrect" and possible differences of nuance." That means you considered my question about "sentence of/for" one you wouldn't like me to ask. But it was absolutely logical based on how you had formulated your own first comment. So the responsibility that I asked it is on you, not on me.

Most (99.99%) native speakers won't do a deep dive into prepositions, but there is a nuanced difference if not a practical one:

imprisonment for five years

refers to a prospective stretch of time.

imprisonment of five years

refers to an attribute of the imprisonment, a length of five years
and

ten years' imprisonment

refers to an imprisonment whose length attribute is ten years.
of five years is a periphrasis of five years'.
Compare :

for the foreseeable future
*of the foreseeable future

